# Jquery, How to get text in span tag using foreach

Tags: jquery

```
<span class='url_link'>1</span>
<span class='url_link'>2</span>
<span class='url_link'>3</span>
<span class='url_link'>4</span>
<span class='url_link'>5</span>

$(".url_link").each(function(idx, obj){
        console.log(this);  // <span class="url_link">
    console.log(this.text()); // TypeError: this.text is not a function
});
```

How can I grep the text in span tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `console.log($(this).text());`

You were trying to use a jQuery function on a non-jQuery object.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fjWJP/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(this.text())
```

Should be

```
console.log($(this).text())
```

`.text()`  is a `jQuery method` and **this** is a `DOM Object` ..

So need to convert that into a jQuery Object before you use `.text()` on it..

If you want to use the native javascript then you can try this

```
console.log(this.innerHTML)
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/awLbp/)**